# Kernel Panic mt7601uap

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel

I wanted to create a wifi hotspot on my ubuntu 16.04 with mt7601usb wifi adapter .

So I cloned and compiled mt7601uap driver from [here](https://github.com/art567/mt7601uap) which is supposed to be ap only .
But after rebooting im stuck with a kernel panic [(screen shot attached)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68scC.jpg) . Removing the usb and rebooting and blacklisting the driver works but I need the driver to setup a wifi hotspot, any suggestions?

Comment: You should first try one of the release version rather going for building from source.  Have you tried this release version 2.5.3: https://github.com/art567/mt7601uap/releases

Comment: my guess is that driver is not stable for gcc 5 which is ubuntu 16.04's biggest source of breakage

Comment: If its not  is not stable for gcc 5 then what to do. also installing release version 2.5.3 is not successful i get the following error:                        Setting up mt7601uap (2.5.3-deb8) ...
depmod: WARNING: could not open /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/modules.builtin: No such file or directory

Comment: I also tried (https://github.com/anthony96922/mt7601u-ap) but with same kernel panic